# Magento directing all link for pages and admin to old domain except the homepage

Tags: magento2, admin, cms, base-url, setup-di-compile

I have done all magento things which were supposed update the `core_config data` table

```
setup:di:compile
```

setup configured base_url through command line  and also done with n98

My site home page is only working fine but I try to direct it to other pages and admin
then It replace new domain URL with old URL

My menu Items are also not shown after migration

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've not overridden the link_url.
If you run the following mysql query

`select * from core_config_data data where path like '%_url%';`

That should show you what urls may still point to the old url.

Also clear the cache just in case

Comment: You saved my day!!!